# How to change highlight color in Jquery Mobile Select Option

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile

I have this select option

[image]

Is it possible to change the highlight color from `skyblue` to other `color`?

I'm using `jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js/css`

Note: I'm also trying to edit in developer tools but I can't find any editable element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not do this.It is default behaviour of dropdown.There are some methods to do this.But these are not working in all browsers.
Better convert your `<select>` to `<ul><li>` format and do whatever you want.

Otherwise,use jQuery Mobile `data-native-menu="false"` property of dropdown :

```
<select id="selectID" data-native-menu="false">
  <option value="one">One</option>
  <option value="two">Two</option>
  <option value="three">Three</option>
  <option value="four">Four</option>
</select>
```

And use following css :

```
 .ui-selectmenu-list .ui-btn-active {
    background-color: green !important;
    border-color: green !important;
    }
```

Comment: this is the right answer. If also want the hover effect you can add this here: .ui-selectmenu-list .ui-btn:hover { background-color: green !important;}

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the class you need to modify is `ui-state-active`

Ex:

```
.ui-state-active {
   background: red;
}
```